# how to create pop window on text box click in jsp page using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have created jsp page to display all surveys from database mysql and display in tabular form.When click on textfield it should show popup with full detail of that survey clicked.

jsp page

```
   <sql:setDataSource var="myDS" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/survey" user="root" password="root" />
    <sql:query var="listUsers"   dataSource="${myDS}">
        SELECT * FROM surveydetail
    </sql:query>
    <div align="center">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="5" class="tableview">
            <h2>List of Survey</h2>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Question</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers.rows}">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" value="<c:out value="${user.questionId}" />" readonly></td> 
                    <td><input type="text" value="<c:out value="${user.questionName}"/>" class="open" name="questionname" readonly> </td>
                     <c:set var="questionid" value="${user.questionId}"/>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
    
    <div class="popup-overlay">
        <div class="popup-content">
            <h2>Pop-Up</h2>
            <sql:query var="SingleUser"   dataSource="${myDS}">
                SELECT * FROM surveydetail where questionId=?
                 <sql:param value="${questionid}" /> 
            </sql:query>
            
                    <c:if  test="${SingleUser.selectType}=='multiple'">
                    <label><c:out value="${SingleUser.surveyTitle}" /></label> <br>
                    <label><c:out value="${SingleUser.questionName}" /></label> <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check1"><input type="text" id="t1" name="txt1" value=<c:out value="${SingleUser.optionOne}" />readonly><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check2"><input type="text" id="t2" name="txt2" value=<c:out value="${SingleUser.optionTwo}" />readonly><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check3"><input type="text" id="t3" name="txt3" value=<c:out value="${SingleUser.optionThree}" />readonly><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check4"><input type="text" id="t4" name="txt4" value=<c:out value="${SingleUser.optionFour}" />readonly>
                    </c:if >
            
                    <c:if  test="${SingleUser.selectType}=='single'">
                    <label><c:out value="${SingleUser.surveyTitle}" /></label> <br>
                    <label><c:out value="${SingleUser.questionName}" /></label> <br>
                    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="radioval"><input type="text" id="t1" name="txt1" value=<c:out value="${SingleUser.optionOne}" />readonly> <br>
                    <input type="radio" id="r2" name="radioval"><input type="text" id="t2" name="txt2" value=<c:out value="${SingleUser.optionTwo}" />readonly> <br>
                    <input type="radio" id="r3" name="radioval"><input type="text" id="t3" name="txt3" value=<c:out value="${SingleUser.optionThree}" />readonly> <br>
                    <input type="radio" id="r4" name="radioval"><input type="text" id="t4" name="txt4" value=<c:out value="${SingleUser.optionFour}" />readonly>
                    </c:if >
            
                    <c:if test="${SingleUser.selectType}=='short'">
                    <label for="title"><c:out value="${SingleUser.surveyTitle}" /></label> <br>
                    <label for="title"><c:out value="${SingleUser.questionName}" /></label> <br>
                    <input type="text" id="txt1" value=<c:out value="${SingleUser.shortAnswer}" />readonly>
                </c:if> 
            
            <input type="button" class="close" value="Close">  
        </div>
        </div>
<form method="post" action="CreateSurveyView.jsp">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="addDetail" name="add" value="Create New Survey" >
        </div>
    </form>
```

css file
I created 2 div by default they are hidden when click on text box should enable div

```
.popup-overlay {
visibility:hidden;
}

.popup-content {
visibility:hidden;
}
.popup-overlay.active{
visibility:visible;
}

.popup-content.active {
visibility:visible;
}
```

jquery: on open and close class

```
$(".open").on("click", function(e){
        $(".popup, .popup-content").addClass("active");
        });
    
    alert("popup");
    $(".close, .popup").on("click", function(){
        $(".popup, .popup-content").removeClass("active");
        });
```

Comment: Not clear what the specific problem is or where this full detail source comes from

Comment: on text box click not showing popup

Comment: `$(".open").on("click", function(e){` this should be `$(document).on("click",".open" ,function(e){` and this `$(".close, .popup").on("click", function(){` should be `$(document).on("click",".close", function(e){` make these changes and let me know if that works or not .

Comment: popup is working fine but still not showing value

Comment: can we use <c:if> to check result set in jstl?

Comment: yes you can use .Does you browser console showing any error ?

Comment: it is showing error some syntax error

Comment: <c:when  test="${listUser.selectType == 'multiple'}"> this is correct??

Comment: <sql:query var="listUser"   dataSource="${myDS}">

Comment: @jyotsnashekhar you didn't get `${listUser.rows}` for second query ? how you are getting data without using resultset ? that the reason of error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217212/discussion-between-jyotsna-shekhar-and-swati).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly pass the value of `questionId` to your second query , you either need to submit your data and use `${param.yourvalue}` to access in your query or use ajax and passed the `questionId` to any `jsp` page and sent back response to show particular data under `pop-up`.Some changes you need to make in your code for doing same with `ajax` :

Your **jsp** page :

```
 <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers.rows}">
     <tr>
       <td>
     <!--added this hidden field which will have questionId value-->
       <input type="text" name ="qid" value="<c:out value="${user.questionId}"/>" hidden> <input type="text" value="<c:out value="${user.questionName}" />" readonly></td> 
        <td><input type="text" value="<c:out value="${user.surveyTitle}"/>" class="open" name="questionname" readonly> </td>
          </tr>
   </c:forEach>
```

Your **pop-up** should look like below :

```
<div class="popup-overlay">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <!--here result will come from ajax-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Your **jquery** code should be like below :

```
$(document).on("click", ".open", function(e) {
      //getting question id
      var qid = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='qid']").val();
    alert(qid);//to test
      $.ajax({
        url: "yourjsppage", //any jsp page or servlet
        data: {
          qid: qid
        }, //pass the data
        success: function(response) {
          //putting  response under div
          $(".popup-content").html(response);
          //show popup
          $(".popup, .popup-content").addClass("active");
        }

      });
```

Your **server-side**(any jsp or servlet) page :

```
//get qid which is passed from ajax
 String qid = (String) request.getParameter("qid");
 String query = "SELECT * FROM surveydetail where questionId=?";
 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
 ps.setString(1, qid);
 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
 //if value rlated to that id is exist
 if (rs.next()) {
  //see  the selectType
  if (rs.getString("selectType").equals("multiple")) {
   //this will go back to ajax response
   out.println("<label>" + rs.getString("surveyTitle") + "</label> <br><label>" + rs.getString("questionName") + "</label> <br>");
   out.println("<input type='checkbox' name='check1'>" + "<input type='text' id='t1' name='txt1' value=" + rs.getString("optionOne") + " readonly><br>");
   out.println("<input type='checkbox' name='check2'>" + "<input type='text' id='t2' name='txt2' value=" + rs.getString("optionTwo") + " readonly><br>");
   out.println("<input type='checkbox' name='check3'>" + "<input type='text' id='t3' name='txt3' value=" + rs.getString("optionThree") + " readonly><br>");
   out.println("<input type='checkbox' name='check4'>" + "<input type='text' id='t4' name='txt4' value=" + rs.getString("optionFour") + " readonly><br>");

  } else if (rs.getString("selectType").equals("single")) {
   //this will go back to ajax response
   out.println("<label>" + rs.getString("surveyTitle") + "</label> <br><label>" + rs.getString("questionName") + "</label> <br>");
   out.println("<input type='radio' name='r1'>" + "<input type='text' id='t1' name='txt1' value=" + rs.getString("optionOne") + " readonly><br>");
   out.println("<input type='radio' name='r2'>" + "<input type='text' id='t2' name='txt2' value=" + rs.getString("optionTwo") + " readonly><br>");
   out.println("<input type='radio' name='r3'>" + "<input type='text' id='t3' name='txt3' value=" + rs.getString("optionThree") + " readonly><br>");
   out.println("<input type='radio' name='r4'>" + "<input type='text' id='t4' name='txt4' value=" + rs.getString("optionFour") + " readonly><br>");


  } else {
   //this will go back to ajax response for short
   out.println("<label>" + rs.getString("surveyTitle") + "</label> <br><label>" + rs.getString("questionName") + "</label> <br>");
   out.println("<input type='text' id='txt1' name='txt1' value=" + rs.getString("shortAnswer") + " readonly><br>");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks swati for your help :)

Comment: can we use this servlet content to new jsp file

Comment: yes you add that add above code in jsp page instead of servlet

Comment: but i want this data directed to new jsp not on <div> .popup-content

Comment: then don't use ajax ..You can use `form` submit  and send your value to jsp page and use same above servlet code there that should work fine.

Comment: can i use jstl code to display data and upon that can I perform update query

Comment: when I am clicking on text box displaying all survey onclick="window.location.href='EditSurvey.jsp'" It takes to editsurvey.jsp but when accessing values it showing null values